# Style Toolbar From App Theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

There are a million questions and articles out there about Android themes and styles - I've read half of them and [I'm still going crazy](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/19/styles-on-android/).

All I want - and coming from a background in web app development with lovely, friendly old CSS stylesheets I thought this would be easy - is to create a theme for my app, and specify in that theme the colour for my toolbars (I'm specifying them per-Activity, which I think is the right thing to do after reading [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)).

So, in my `styles.xml` file I've got:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

To my mind, I have here created a style for my toolbars, then referenced that style in my theme. I have then set my theme as the application theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

And for the most part, that works. There are other styles referenced in my theme, which I've omitted from my code for the sake of simplicity, and they work correctly - my buttons, textviews and so on are styled as per the styles I've created.

But the pesky toolbars are not. I've tried referecing my style directly in the toolbar xml (even though I don't see why I should need to if it's specified in the theme):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyToolbar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This, frustratingly, does cause the background colour of the toolbar to be as I want it, but the text remains black, even though I'm trying to make it white.

Have I misunderstood the way themes reference styles and are then applied to activities or the whole application? Is there something unique about toolbars? It's taken me longer to try and figure this out than to write the whole rest of the app from scratch, and it's my first Android app!

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so I've worked out that whilst my toolbar's background colour needs to be set in a *style* applied to the toolbar, to prevent that background colour being propogated to all child views, the desired text colour needs to specified in a *theme* because the text displayed in the toolbar is a child view (even though I can't see it in my activity's xml). So, this works:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

**main_activity.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
    app:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

So I guess I've achieved what I wanted, but I haven't answered my original question: why isn't the toolbar styling applied implicitly from my theme? Why do I have to declare it explicitly in the markup for my toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/MyToolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/TextStyle"/>
```

Additionally, read this [information](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/) here to get an idea about style and theme. Refer [this](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/) link here.

Comment: Ok, well this does make my toolbar text white, but it also styles everything INSIDE the toolbar as a toolbar too, so the text in the toolbar has a raised appearance itself, just like the toolbar. Not sure how to include a screenshot  in a comment. However, this is sort of what I'd expect, since I imagine that applying a THEME rather than a STYLE to the toolbar styles not only that view but also the child views? Which isn't what I want.

Comment: I don't have a "TextStyle" defined, so that doesn't work. I could create one, but then all I'd be doing is overriding a theme inherited from the toolbar that I didn't want in the first place. I only want to style the toolbar itself, not its children. Unless the text in the toolbar is, in fact, a child of the toolbar? I'm not even sure the author of that article you linked to is entirely clear on the difference between themes and styles. Not only is their intended scope different, they have different attributes.

Comment: When you apply a style to your toolbar, all its child will get affected. That's why the popupTheme is there. Read about the default toolbar themes in Android docs and use it as your theme. See the link I've added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbar</item>
```

instead of:

```
<item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbar</item>
```

works great.